# Permission denied (publickey) copy from remote machine to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp

I'm facing an issue and it's driving me crazy about ssh authentication!

So, I could copy file from local machine to remote, but when I want to copy file from remote machine to local it raises me **Permission denied (publickey)**

I was trying to copy file from remote to local like this:

```
scp ubuntu@ip-10-248-32-56:/home/ubuntu/queries.txt dusanristic@Dusans-MacBook-Air:~/

sudo scp -r ubuntu@ip-10-245-82-139:~/events.json.gz /Users/dusanristic/events.json.gz
```

Also I've followed some directions about how to configure remote machine in order to be able to execute **scp** command correctly **here:** [ssh set up and use](http://www.maths.utas.edu.au/People/Hill/ssh-config.html) ,  below a title **RSA/User Authentication**

I did not manage to make successful!

What shall I do to copy file from remote amazon machine to my local machine?

Comment: Start by using the -v argument to scp or ssh.  This prints useful debugging information.  If you don't figure it out from that, then update your question with that full log.

Comment: could you post your answer here? or how did you proceed?

Answer (score -1):

create the following file on the remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys and paste your user's (dusanristic) public key to that file. Your public key is most probably called id_rsa.pub and should be on your local computer most probably under ~dusanristic/.ssh/